# Ruby: loops and difference in rescuing

Tags: ruby, loops

I'm studying Ruby and I'm quite frustrated. Here are three code examples which are meant to do the same thing:

**Example 1**

```
animals = %w(dog cat horse goat snake frog)
count = 0

begin
    animals.each do |animal|
        puts "The current animal is #{animal}"
        break if count == 10
        count += 1
        raise if animal == 'horse'
    end
    rescue
        retry
end
```

It works fine. I tried to do the same trick with `for` (and perhaps I got lost in the sequence ending):

**Example 2**

```
animals = %w(dog cat horse goat snake frog)
count = 0

for animal in animals
    begin
        puts "The current animal is #{animal}"
        break if count == 10
        count += 1
        raise if animal == 'horse'
    end
    rescue
       retry
end
```

It doesn't work (`syntax error, unexpected keyword_rescue, expecting keyword_end`).

Here I tried to use retry inside a for loop (well, it actually was my first try), but instead of retrying the whole loop it just retries current iteration, giving out a dog, a cat and a bunch of horses:

**Example 3**

```
animals = %w(dog cat horse goat snake frog)
count = 0

for animal in animals
begin
    puts "The current animal is #{animal}"
    break if count == 10
    count += 1
    raise if animal == 'horse'
    rescue
        retry
    end
end
```

So what am I doing wrong? Is retrying inside a loop a wrong idea overall? Why do `each` and `for` loops work differently here? How do I make a correct retry from `for` loop?

Based on this thread: https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/getting-an-error-when-practicing-retry-command-in-forloops

Comment: For starters, try indenting things consistently

Comment: Put `for` _inside_ of `begin` and `rescue` outside of `for`, because this is what you have in the first example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better way to use a counter for your first example would be

```
begin
  animals.each_with_index do |animal, count|
    puts "The current animal is #{animal}"
    break if count == 10
    count += 1
    raise if animal == 'horse'
  end
rescue
  retry # should be next
end
```

But that is a continous loop because you do a retry which keeps getting the horse back and so raising an error etc, you could use next instead but if you just want to show all the animals without the horse the following is more 'rubyesque'. First you select all the non 'horse' animals, then you limit the result to the first 10.

```
animals
  .reject{|animal| animal == 'horse'}
  .take(10)
  .each{|animal| puts "The current animal is #{animal}"}
```

You example with for isn't rubiesque at all but here the adjusted code (indentation !)

```
animals = %w(dog cat horse goat snake frog)
count = 0
for animal in animals
  begin
    puts "The current animal is #{animal}"
    break if count == 10
    count += 1
    raise if animal == 'horse'
  rescue
    retry # or next ?
  end
end
```

Comment: Wow, your 'rubyesque' example is really elegant. I hope I'll be able to make my mind work this way one day.

Answer (score 0):

Your inconsistent indentation makes it hard to spot missing (or misplaced ends) but the key difference between your `for` and `each` loops is where the begin/rescue sits in relation to the `for` or `each`.

`retry` causes ruby to go back to the top of the enclosing begin/rescue (or method) and start executing from there. If that begin is inside the `for` then it will go there, if the `begin` is outside the `for` then the entire for loop will be executed again.